# Hl7- hapi - PID-5.7.2 value

Tags: hl7, hapi

I use hapi java library to parse HL7 file.
I need to access pid-5.7.2 value (=titi):
PID|1||1^^^^||toto^test^^^MME^^L~**titi**^test^^^MME^^D

I can access pid-5.7 value (=L)

```
pidPatient.getPatientName()[0].getXpn7_NameTypeCode().getValue());
```

But how can i get 5.7.2 value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not `PID-5-7-2`, this is the second repetition of the whole `PID-5` segment. `~` is the default repetition symbol in HL7.

My HAPI skills are a bit rusty, but I'd suggest trying something like this to get to the field, where "titi" is. Note the array index **1**.

```
pidPatient.getPatientName()[1].getXpn1_FamilyName().getValue());
```

Comment: It's perfect ! Thank you !